# How to show separate text from 2 listbox on a button click

Tags: button, listbox, click, messagebox

I am a beginner so don't go into to much detail if you can. I want to be able to click a button and a message box to show and gather text from 2 listbox. For example if listbox 1 has the name 'Dean' in it and listbox 2 has the name 'Stowers' in it I want the click to show a message box saying 'Dean Stowers'. I can only get text from one box to show, I have no idea who to get it to show both. Here is my code for showing text from one listbox

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object obj in listboxname.Items)          
        {
            MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you want the MessageBox to show the FirstName and the LastName. Is Dean and Stowers currently selected values?

Comment: What is the `ID` of both list boxes? (if you use visual studio, click on each one and see the properties window).

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, I figured it out. It was very simple and I was just missing out a few things.